# How to Transfer Yahoo mail to Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, yahoo-mail

I want to collect my Yahoo mail folders. I tried to transfer Yahoo mail to Thunderbird. When I try to configure Thunderbird, it says that the username or password is incorrect. But actually it's correct.

How do I transfer Yahoo mail to Thunderbird?

Comment: It's a little hard to know why it didn't work if you don't provide any information on where the messages are, what you did, and how you did it.

Comment: When i try to configure thunderbird, it says that the username or password is incorrect. But actually its correct.

Comment: Are you connecting via POP3 or imap? Are you using the correct ports? Are you using SSL? What guide are you following to do this connection?

Comment: See this guide for settings: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail-for-desktop/pop-server-settings-yahoo-mail-sln4724.html?impressions=true

Answer (score 0):

A real good tool for migrating or transfering mails from different services or programm is **[MailStore Home](http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home-email-archiving.aspx)**. You can do nearly everything with the free version.

If your mail account uses POP or IMAP you add your account information to the tool and then download all mails. After the download you can export the mail into a thunderbird profile.

The programm is also able to export mails from outlook/thunderbird/Windows Mail/Windows Live mail/Mozilla sea Monkey or even single mbox or eml/msg files. As well you can import mails to those mentiont programms and file formats

Comment: Please see this link on how to recommend software in an answer: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: Changed tha answer. hope its a bit better now

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer yahoo mail to thunderbird. Mozilla Thunderbird is an email client. You only have to configure it.

Here are some tutorials on configuring Thunderbird:

- [Configure Mozilla Thunderbird for Yahoo! Mail](https://www.wikihow.com/Configure-Mozilla-Thunderbird-for-Yahoo!-Mail)
- [thunderbird and yahoo](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-yahoo)